# Showing Longitude and latitude when touched on screen

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to show the longitude and latitude to user when he or she touch a specific location on the map, how can I do that? I am using Eclipse and Google maps api and this is my school project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This process is called Reverse Geo-coding, Use Google and it will give you everything you want.  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html Visit this link for a tutorial.

Comment: Thanks. :) much appreciated. i just needed a line of action.